# Nifi: How to create a dynamic property for a temporary access token in InvokeHTTP

Tags: variables, dynamic, parameters, properties, apache-nifi

I am using the NiFi InvokeHTTP processor to create a HTTP POST request to a secured/authenticated REST API.

To authenticate at the REST API, I need to call a HTTP POST authentication endpoint with a username and password (stored in a parameter context) first that will return an access token. This access token I can use in the InvokeHTTP for 24h for all requests to the REST API. After 24h I need to re-authenticate with username and password and will get a new access token.

**Where in NiFi could I store the dynamic access token to be used as a property in the InvokeHTTP?** As of my knowledge parameters and variables are not dynamic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300493/executing-nifi-invokehttp-processor-once-during-a-flow-rather-than-on-a-per-inbo/67303487#67303487

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by:

1. In InvokeHTTP adding a property name, e.g. auth_result_body, in "Put Response Headers to Request". This saved the http response (including the access_token) as json to a new attribute
2. Creating a "UpdateAttribute" Processor, adding a new property "access_token" with the value `$(auth_result_body:jsonPath("$.access_token")}` to extract the access token from the json response